# Error Image listview fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpgGe.png)Below is the coding i have and it seems i have problem on the

AgentAdapter adapter = new AgentAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_agent, member_names, profile_pics);

How do i use image and text together for the list adapter i have in my fragment? Please help.

```
public class AgentFragment extends Fragment{




        String[] member_names;
        TypedArray profile_pics;

        ListView mylistview;




       String[] agentname={"Robert","Shanni","Rachel","Mady","Nikhil"};
        Integer [] imgid = {R.drawable.robert,R.drawable.shanni,R.drawable.rachael,R.drawable.maddy_pic,R.drawable.nikhil_pic};

        public AgentFragment(){

        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout1, null);
            setupList(view);

            return view;
        }
        private void setupList(View view){
            AgentAdapter adapter = new AgentAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_agent, member_names, profile_pics);
            mylistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its possible that the fragment has not been placed in any activity at runtime you can afford for this by changing the `getActivity()` to be the context from the `view` parameter:

```
private void setupList(View view){
    AgentAdapter adapter = new AgentAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.list_agent, member_names, profile_pics);
    mylistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Hello there Petey thanks for you reply.. Sorry i never post the full coding because it'll be long.. The main activity is having this fragment as part of a navigation view